# Doctrine 2.0 Orx not allowed

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm

**Code**

```
$qb->andWhere(
   $qb->expr()->orx(
        $qb->expr()->andx("p.value_a >= " . $values[0],"p.value_a <= " . $values[1]),
        $qb->expr()->orx(
             $qb->expr()->andx("p.venture_min_value_a >= " . $values[0],"p.venture_min_value_a <= " . $values[1]),
             $qb->expr()->andx("p.venture_max_value_a >= " . $values[0],"p.venture_max_value_a <= " . $values[1])
                        )
    ));
```

**Error message:**

> Expression of type 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Orx' not allowed in this
>   context.

**Question**

> orx -> andx -> orx

Is this a doctrine limitation or is it my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [known error](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1260) and will be fixed in the next Doctrine release (Version 2.2)